# [UIView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios

I want to build a tableView cell and add subview to it.But something is wrong in there.The title is the mistake,and language is Objective-c,please help me,thanks!
Here are the subclass of UITableViewCell,it name is NameAndColorCell.

NameAndColorCell.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NameAndColorCell : UITableViewCell

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *color;

@end
```

NameAndColorCell.m:

```
 #import "NameAndColorCell.h"

@interface NameAndColorCell()

@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *colorLabel;

@end

@implementation NameAndColorCell

- (id)initWithStyle : (UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        CGRect nameLabelRect = CGRectMake(0, 5, 70, 15);
        UILabel *nameMaker = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:nameLabelRect];
        nameMaker.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        nameMaker.text = @"Name";
        nameMaker.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [self.contentView addSubview:nameMaker];

        CGRect colorLabelRect = CGRectMake(0, 26, 70, 15);
        UILabel *colorMaker = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:colorLabelRect];
        colorMaker.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        colorMaker.text = @"color";
        colorMaker.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [self.contentView addSubview:colorMaker];

        CGRect nameValueRect = CGRectMake(80, 5, 200, 15);
        _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:nameValueRect];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];

        CGRect colorValueRect = CGRectMake(80, 25, 200, 15);
        _colorLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:colorValueRect];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_colorLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)n{
    if (![n isEqualToString:_name]) {
        _name = [n copy];
        self.nameLabel.text = _name;
    }
}

- (void)setColor:(NSString *)c{
    if (![c isEqualToString:_color]) {
        _color = [c copy];
        self.colorLabel.text = _color;
    }
}

@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NameAndColorCell.h"

static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";
@interface ViewController ()

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSArray *computer;

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.computer = @[@{@"Name" : @"MacBook Air", @"Color" : @"Silver"},
                      @{@"Name" : @"MacBook Pro", @"Color" : @"Silver"},
                      @{@"Name" : @"iMac", @"Color" : @"Silver"},
                      @{@"Name" : @"MacMini", @"Color" : @"Silver"},
                      @{@"Name" : @"Mac Pro", @"Color" : @"Black"}];

    UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [tableView registerClass:[NameAndColorCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = tableView.contentInset;
    contentInset.top = 20;
    [tableView setContentInset:contentInset];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.computer count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NameAndColorCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *rowData = self.computer[indexPath.row];
    cell.name = rowData[@"Name"];
    cell.color = rowData[@"Color"];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I set the value of tag as 1.

Comment: it returns the `UIView` not a `UITableView`, check once your tag is correct or not else you assigned the same tag for some another view also

Comment: UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
 is wrong tag

Comment: else use `UITableView *tableView = (UITableView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];`

Comment: Why are you using tags in the first place? Why not just store reference to the table view?

Comment: I want to visit table view that don't need to add any specified property, and thanks all,I found the mistake I made and fix the issue already.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to cast it like

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: do this can't fix the issue, but thanks anyway,I fix it already.

Comment: what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
`UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1]`
```

returns the UIView not a UITableView. You need to cast it properly to UITableView. You should use

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Instead of accessing TableView using its tag you can create IBOutlet for the same.

If you are using prototype cell in storyboard registerClass is not required.